# valor passado via Service não está sendo atualizado no segundo controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-services

Procurei como compartilhar um *scope* entre dois *controllers*, e vi que uma opção seria o *service* ou um *factory* que utilizam o *padrão singleton*, porém eu já tentei os dois e o que acontece é que não consigo setar o valor de um controller pro outro, no exemplo abaixo queria que imprimisse *exemplo.com.br* porém está imprimindo *teste*.

**Primeiro controller**

```
app.controller('ctrRelatorioBolsaPorOrientador', ['$scope','$http', '$filter', '$routeParams', 'PropriedadesCompartilhadas',function($scope, $http, $filter, $routeParams, PropriedadesCompartilhadas) {

            $scope.url_grafico  =  'exemplo.com.br';
            PropriedadesCompartilhadas.set($scope.url_grafico);
}
```

**Segundo controller**

```
app.controller('ctrRelatorioBolsaPorOrientadorPdf', ['$scope','$http', '$filter', '$routeParams', 'PropriedadesCompartilhadas',function($scope, $http, $filter, $routeParams, PropriedadesCompartilhadas) {

      $scope.url_grafico = PropriedadesCompartilhadas.get();
}
```

**app.js (factory)**

```
var app = angular.module("sicite", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ngSanitize", "ui.bootstrap", "ngPasswordMeter", "angular-loading-bar", "googlechart"]);

app.factory('PropriedadesCompartilhadas', function() {
    var valor = 'teste';

    function set(data) {
        valor = data;
    }
    function get() {
        return valor;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }

});
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está referenciando um valor literal.

Um literal é sua própria instância: Quando você atualiza o valor de `url_grafico` você está associando um novo valor literal. Seu segundo *controller* não receberá o valor atualizado.

No exemplo abaixo o valor de `url_grafico` é armazenado como uma propriedade de um objeto. Este objeto é então compartilhado; o segundo controle recebe uma referência a ele.

```js
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.factory('PropriedadesCompartilhadas', function() {
    this.dados = {};
    return this;
})
.controller('ctrRelatorioBolsaPorOrientador', function($scope, PropriedadesCompartilhadas) {
  $scope.setarValor = function(){
    PropriedadesCompartilhadas.dados.url_grafico = 'exemplo.com.br';
  };
})
.controller('ctrRelatorioBolsaPorOrientadorPdf', function($scope,PropriedadesCompartilhadas) {
  $scope.dados = PropriedadesCompartilhadas.dados;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='ctrRelatorioBolsaPorOrientador' style='border:1px solid red'>
  <button ng-click='setarValor()'>Setar Valor</button>
  </div><br/>
  <div ng-controller='ctrRelatorioBolsaPorOrientadorPdf' style='border:1px solid blue'>
  
  {{dados.url_grafico}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não está atualizando ainda, será que é por eu estar utilizando os js separados do app.js para os controllers? vou dar uma olhada, as vezes to comendo bola, mas tá retornando **{}** agora